# How to extract all links (href + text) from a page with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to extract all the links on a page, and from each link I need to get the `href` and its respective `text`.

If any page has a total of 3 links:

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">This is the Stackoverflow page</a>
<a href="https://example.com">This is an example link</a>
<a href="tel:+99999999999">This is my phone</a>
```

I would need a result like this:

```
links = {
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com": "This is the Stackoverflow page",
    "https://example.com": "This is an example link",
    "tel:+99999999999": "This is my phone"
}
```

So the goal is to know that the `text` X belongs to `href` Y, and the page is not specific, it can be any one.

I've tried two other ways to no avail:

1. Returns only `href`:

   ```
   for r in response.css('a::attr(href)').getall():
       print(r)
   ```
2. Does not return the `href`, only the `text`

   ```
   le = LinkExtractor()
   for link in le.extract_links(response):
      print(link.url)
      print(link.text)
   ```

And it needs to be with Scrapy, BeautifulSoup doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep with the format you posted:

```
for r in response.css('a'):
    url = r.css('::attr(href)').get()
    txt = r.css('::text').get()
```

`response.css('a')` will return a list of [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

`r` will be a different selector in each iteration of the for loop.

Since `r` is a selector, you can use the `.css()` (or `.xpath()`) method to access any path or attribute of that node. In this case, text and href.